# Teams Outgoing Webhook Bot is not sending 'imBack' or 'messageBack' to my Bot

Tags: node.js, botframework, microsoft-teams

I am creating a bot called `IRBot` - incident response bot. The code sample i am following is here: https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/outgoing-webhook/nodejs

I want to be able to simple @ the bot (e.g. type @IRBot) and the default case to return a thumbnail card containing an option to click a button (there will be 3 buttons). Essentially this thumbnail card will say 'which team would you like to raise an alert with'. When you press the button you want, I simply want to send back a message/data to the same bot, which will then handle and raise the alert accordingly.

So essentially my switch case will have four options:

1. `alert-me`
2. `alert-team2`
3. `alert-team3`
4. `default` - this will just display some info about the bot, and 3 buttons hooked up to the above options.

If i type '@IRBot alert-me' it works exactly as I require.

However, I cannot get it to work with either `imBack` or `messageBack` (docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-actions?tabs=json)

With `imBack` I see in the thread of the conversation 'IRBot alert-me' (with IRBot highlighted Blue, as if you'd @ it) but nothing happens - nothing is actually sent back to the bot.

With `messageBack` I simply get an error message 'Something went wrong. Please try again'.

```
responseMsg = {
    type: "message",
    attachments: [
        {
            contentType: "application/vnd.microsoft.card.thumbnail",
            content: {
                title: "IRBot - Incident Response Bot.",
                subtitle: "Choose one of the following options:",
                text: "This is a Bot that will immediately page any of the following teams, including out-of-hours. This should be used for Major Incidents only.",
                images: [
                    {
                        url: "myredactedurl",
                        alt: "IRBot"
                    }
                ],
                buttons: [
                    {
                        type: "imBack",
                        title: "alert-me-imBack",                                                    
                        value: "alert-me"
                    },
                    {
                        type: "messageBack",
                        title: "alert-me-messageBack",                                                    
                        value: "alert-me"
                    }
                ],
                "tap": {
                    "type": "imBack",
                    "value": "Tapped it!"
                  }
            }
        }
    ]
};
```

Can anyone please tell me where I'm going wrong here? Thanks.

Comment: @kafka-We are able to repro that issue, we have raised bug for the same. We will inform you once we get any update.

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT can I just check something: 
"Responses appear in the same chain as the original request message and can include any Bot Framework message content. For example, rich text, images, cards, and emojis. Although Outgoing Webhooks can use cards, they can't use any card actions except for openURL." 
taken from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/add-outgoing-webhook?tabs=urljsonpayload%2Cdotnet#key-features-of-outgoing-webhooks